# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column '6' in 'where clause': SELECT

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-3-upgrade

I am upgrading my Rails app from Rails 2.3 to 3.2.
and I am getting this weird error

`Mysql2::Error: Unknown column '6' in 'where clause':`

above error is due to `(backtick) which is applied to data in the where clause along with the column names see the following query.

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column '6' in 'where clause': SELECT `users`.`username`,`users`.`password` FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (`6`)
```

see the 6 even though it is data activerecord is applying backtick to it.because of that mysql is raising exception.

NOTE:This is usually seen while calling related object(one to one,many to many)

eg:

```
 u = User.where(:active =>true).each{|u|
   //some code
    u.user_role #error will raise in this line 
    }
```

if I reinitiate the object it will work fine.

```
  u = User.where(:active =>true).each{|u|
   //some code
    u.user_role #error will raise in this line
    u1 = User.find(u.id)
    u1.user_role #works fine. 

    }
```

**This is happening throughout the application and with other models as well,above code snippet is just one instance.**

Environment details:

OS: Ubuntu 13.10,Ruby 1.9.3-p545,Rails 3.2.17 mysql 5.5

Anyone knows what going on here ? is it because of gem incompatibility ? 
Please let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: for me it seams there is something happening in your `//some code` stuff (checking credentials? although loading passwords and not password_digest seems a bit wierd too) your actual query should look something like `SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."active" = 't'`

Comment: @jethroo I renamed the columns before posting,ya I agree Ideally the query should look like as you have shown but it in my case its select `table_name`.`column1`,`table_name`.`column2`...`table_name`.`lastcolumn` from table where id in (`11`),it selects all the column but it doesn't do `table_name`.*.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to gem incompatibility.I was using 'slim_scrooge' gem to optimize queries in Rails 2.X doesn't gem well with Rails 3 or higher.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why this may be coming, but I think you can avoid this and an extra query to sql while accessing `user_role` by using `include` in your query. This will eager load `user_role` in the first query itself and will not make extra query in each loop.

Code will be something like following:

```
  u = User.where(:active =>true).includes(:user_roles).each{|u|
    //some code
     u.user_role #error will raise in this line 
     }
```

More details on include is here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes

Comment: This is happening throughout the application I can't do this all over the app.